# Analysis of a multiple-selection qualitative variable

Tags: r

I am analyzing the months of the year when the sale is high.  Initially there are 12 modalities or 12 months. Respondents can choose one, two, three or even 12 months.  This means that we have several combinations of modalities.... I split each modality as a variable with 1 and 0 as new modalities.  My goal is to get the frequency of each month, is there a way to build the contingency table with the gtsummary package?

I will use the gtsummary package to get a contingency table

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow :-) You need to include some debugging information in your question. Code, and/or data (`dput(df)`) is great.